# Editable supercript/subscript in editText android

Tags: android, android-edittext, calculator

How to dynamically create edittext's at the superscript or subscript position, like a scientific calculator?

How to read them back in a formatted string ?

Sample app using this:

[malmath scientific calculator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.malmath.apps.mm)

[image: malmath image with dynamic edittext's]

Comment: read about `SuperscriptSpan` / `SubscriptSpan` and  `android.text.Spannable` (for setting spans) and `android.text.Spanned` (for reading spans) interfaces

Comment: Can you please elaborate, I don't think  we can add new text inputs dynamically with  Spans

Comment: what `text inputs`?

Comment: In malmath scientific calculator above, if you press the integral sign, it automatically adds 6 input fields (boxes). Aren't they text inputs?